# How to redirect both non-www and www AND http to https server-side (but at the same time)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a domain https://www.demo.com . The problem is that when I put demo.com in my browser, there are 2 redirects occurring in the browser:

http://demo.com > https://demo.com > https://www.demo.com

Screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/xcK1labt3

As you can see, the server actually returns 2 redirects, which slows the loading.

Does anyone know a way to put both the HTTP and non-www conversions in one request? So if I put demo.com, then the server just returns https://www.demo.com

Here's my current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.demo.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try appending [OR] to your first RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
```

It should help evaluating both conditions, so your RewriteRule can take place, even if only first RewriteCond is false. Not providing the [OR] flag makes it a [AND] by default.